# .get no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá. Eu estou começando em python, e vi o seguinte tutorial:

```
phone_num = input("Numero De Telefone: ")


Mapa_De_Digitos = {
    "1": "Um",
    "2": "Dois",
    "3": "Três",
    "4": "Quatro"
}
output = ""
for ch in phone_num:
    output += Mapa_De_Digitos.get(ch, "") + " "
print(output)
```

A minha Duvida é: Eu não entendo este ".get" , eu nunca vi isso em nenhum livro\pdf aqui. Eu não estou entendendo este código.

Não sei se é permitido este tipo de explicação aqui nesta comunidade, mas eu gostaria muito de uma explicação bem simples para leigos entenderem.

Comment: Acho que acabei de entender. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado:

# Se "ch" do IMPUT for igual á Chave da Lista Mapa_De_Digitos -> O Metodo "get"
#...mostra o valor (chave\Valor) correspondente do item da lista.

Comment: Seu loop "for" irá varrer todos dígitos do seu input, um por um, colocando na variável "ch" e irá testar se o mesmo corresponde a alguma chave do seu dicionário "Mapa_De_Digitos", se corresponder, irá imprimir o valor por extenso e se não existir uma chave igual a "ch", irá imprimir uma string vazia.

Answer (score 5):

O `get()` é um método usado para pegar o valor de uma dada chave em um dicionário se a chave estiver no dicionário, caso ela não exista, o método retorna `None` ou o valor padrão passado por parâmetro.

O `get()` pode ser usado, por exemplo, desta forma:

```
dicionario = {'A': 1, 'B': 2} 
valor = dicionario.get('A')
print(valor)
# Imprime '1' na tela
```

No exemplo acima, usamos apenas um parâmetro, mas o `get()` aceita dois parâmetros:

- A chave a ser pesquisada no dicionário;
- O valor a ser retornado se a chave não for encontrada (opcional).

Usando o mesmo exemplo, agora usando o segundo parâmetro para retornar um valor padrão quando a chave buscada não existe:

```
dicionario = {'A': 1, 'B': 2} 
valor = dicionario.get('C', 'Não encontrado!')
print(valor)
# Imprime 'Não encontrado!' na tela
```

No seu exemplo, o método `get()` está dentro de um loop `for` e este loop é feito em cada caractere da string fornecida pelo usuário na primeira linha.

Por exemplo se eu fornecer `'123'` como entrada, `ch` irá iterar em `'1'`, `'2'` e `'3'` e a execução de `Mapa_De_Digitos.get(ch, "")` vai retornar o valor relativo a chave `ch` em cada iteração do seu loop: `'Um'`, `'Dois'` e `'Três'`.

Se fosse o caso de alguma chave não existir no seu dicionário, uma string vazia `''` seria retornada.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse exemplo,`Mapa_De_Digitos` é um objetto do tipo dicionário, para ver o tipo de um objeto use, `type()`:

```
type(Mapa_De_Digitos)
Out[7]: dict
```

No caso o `get()` é um dos métodos da classe que define o objeto dicionário, para ver os metodos disponíveis em um objeto use `dir(objeto)`, não vou reproduzir abaixo pq a lista é imensa, mas vc pode comprovar que `get()` está na lista de métodos assim:

```
'get' in dir(Mapa_De_Digitos)
Out[9]: True
```

**Definição de `dicionário`:**
Um dicionário em Python é uma estrutura de dados que, ao contrário de sequencias que são indexadas por uma *range* de números, dicionários são indexados por chaves (*keys*), que são tipos imútavies, strings e numeros podem representar estas `keys`, segundo a [propria documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), a melhor forma de pensar um dicionário e como um conjunto de pares de chave:valor (*key:value*). com a restrição de que as chaves tem que ser únicas (dentro de um dicionario), um dicionario vazio é definico por um par chaves (*braces*)

**O método `get()`:**
 
O método recupera o valor atribuido à chave que voce envia como argumento para o método, mas também voce pode fazer isso com formato `dict[key]`, veja abaixo:

```
Mapa_De_Digitos.get("4")
Out[14]: 'Quatro'

Mapa_De_Digitos["4"]
Out[15]: 'Quatro'
```

A vantagem do método `get()` é que ele sempre retorna algo, se a chave não existe, o valor `None` é retornado, enquanto que no formato com os parenteses uma exceção de erro é levantada quando a chave não existe, veja:

```
nine = Mapa_De_Digitos.get(9)
print(nine)
None

nine = Mapa_De_Digitos[9]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-bb87d7f1428a> in <module>()
----> 1 nine = Mapa_De_Digitos[9]

KeyError: 9
```